# include_path directive in php.ini affects looking first at the current directory when writting an unqualified name of a file?

Tags: php, file, ini, include-path

this directive allows to set paths where file functions will look for a file that is written as an unqualified name (e.g. hello.txt). my question in this case is: does these functions always look first in the current directory and then in the paths that are written in the include_path directory? or does these functions look first in the current directory because the first path is "." that means the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

When you're performing a file operation, PHP "looks" at the current working directory. You can get that directory by calling [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getcwd.php). I found that rather confusing in the beginning, because it can lead to "unexpected" behaviour when using relativ paths (like your "unqualified file name"), that's why it got into the habit of always using `__DIR__` (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to define the starting location. Example:

```
//script location: /foo/bar/example.php

$filename = "hello.txt";
$filepath = __DIR__."/".$filename;
// $filepath is /foo/bar/hello.txt
```

The `include_path` will be taken into account, if you try to `include` or `require` another file into your php script but has nothin to do with file based operations.

Comment: I didn't understand when php will go to the paths in the include_path. I thought that only if you write the file name without preceding it with directories (e.g. hello.text). if you write the relative path to the file it will also look for it in the include_path?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide an example that clarifies your problem.

Comment: for example: fopen('hello.txt', 'r+' , true) will this go automatically to look for the file in the current directory, or it will go by order to the paths that are written in include_path? another example is: fopen('foo/hello.txt' 'r+', true) will this go to the include_path or it will only look for the file in the foo sub folder of the current directory?

Comment: I think this explains it the best way: Filesystem is the default wrapper used with PHP and represents the local filesystem. When a relative path is specified (a path which does not begin with /, \, \\, or a Windows drive letter) the path provided will be applied against the current working directory.With some functions, such as fopen() and file_get_contents(), include_path may be optionally searched for relative paths as well.

Comment: so when specifying relative path in file function then it will first go the current directory and then could also look for it in the include_path

Comment: Yes. It'll first look in the current directory and only after that (if use_include_path is true) will use the include path.